# How do I tell what component is preventing my computer from booting for the first time?

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard, computer-building

This is the build:

- Intel Core i3-4130T Haswell
- MSI H81M-P33 LGA 1150 Intel H81
- CORSAIR CX series CX430 430W ATX12V v2.3 80 PLUS BRONZE
- ADATA XPG V1.0 series 4GB 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory Model AX3U1600GC4G9-1G

When I attempt to boot, I see the CPU fans spin for a half second and then shut down.  I have tried re-applying thermal paste (after cleaning it carefully with a new cloth and ArctiClean 1 & 2), with no luck (same problem).

I tested out the power supply's 24-pin and it's good with +3.3V, -12V, PG, +5VSB, +12V, and +5V (only light that does not turn on is -5V).

I'm not sure how to test out whether the RAM is the issue since I don't have any other compatible sticks of RAM in the house. Also not sure how to test whether the motherboard is the issue.

All parts were bought new. This is the second computer I have put together.

Comment: Without additional parts all you can do is replace each part until it works.  Any of the parts you listed could be the problem and we can't diagnose the problem given the information you provided.

Comment: I tested with another stick of RAM; same issue - so it's not the RAM.  I have a power supply tester - amazon.com/gp/product/B005CTCD6S - but it shows all is well (-5V apparently doesn't matter).  Is there any other way of testing the PSU without replacing it?

Comment: The way to trouleshoot this kind of issue is to remove all hardware that can be removed and see if it POSTs. Then, progressively put stuff back in until you find the component that breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like an overheating problem, or a missing fan sensor connection.  Given the immediate shutdown, it sounds unlikely to be a real overheating situation.

Based on the description, I'm assuming the power turns off abruptly.  If not, post codes may be able to help - check that the speaker is connected properly.  Also try removing all but the essential equipement.

And, as @Ramhound suggests, swapping parts is your best bet - if you have some known-good ones; preferrably using parts from a compatible system that runs.

Comment: The speaker is plugged in but doesn't make any sound. I'm fairly certain that the speaker is connected properly, although the documentation is a bit weird - the speaker is a 4-pin, and the JFP2 connectors are also 4-pin. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/FTfxyFW.png) is a screenshot from the manual.

Comment: If your not even getting a BIOS beep then it's either hardware failure or a missing connection

Comment: Might sound ridiculous, but are 1x4 12v power connectors connected to the PSU?

Comment: Not ridiculous at all... do you mean [this](http://www.endpcnoise.com/e/images/atx12v.jpg) one?  I read online that it's optional, but figured I would pick one up at the store today... just gonna venture a guess and say it's not optional :(